# python, validate custom return type

Tags: python, validation, return-type, typing

How can I validate the return type of a method in python?
Let's say the `myfunc` **returns** a **list of tuples**, I'd like to have something like:

```
def myfunc() :
    return [(1,2), (3,4)]
```

I tried to use `typing`, `TypeVal`

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type
def myfunc() -> list[tuple]:
   ...
```

or something like:

```
list_tup = list[tuple]
def myfunc(t: Type[T]) -> list_tup :
    ...
```

> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

What is the correct syntax or how can I validate a custom return type?

Answer (score 2):

Python's `typing` package provides what you are looking for, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#corresponding-to-built-in-types) for specifics on collections. But you are looking for something like this:

```py
from typing import Tuple, List

def myfunc() -> List[Tuple[int]]:
  ...
```

That being said python's type annotations does not quite "validate" anything, and are implemented to allow IDEs to perform better syntax highlighting and help make python code  bit more readable. From [pep 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#rationale-and-goals):

> Of these goals, static analysis is the most important. This includes support for off-line type checkers such as mypy, as well as providing a standard notation that can be used by IDEs for code completion and refactoring.

For example the following snippet is valid even though the marked return type and actual return type differ:

```py
def fn() -> str:
  return 5
```

If you *really* want to strictly validate the return type you can place some conditions at the end:

```py
def myfunc():
  val = list()

  if not isinstance(list, val):
    ...
```

However, this is realistically not the most useful approach since given the right inputs you should always produce the same type. So any type validations should be done at the beggining of a function on the parameters if any  type validations are going to be done.

Comment: It might be worth noting that from Python 3.9 onwards the code listed in the question will actually work.

Answer (score 1):

`list` and `tuple` can't be used in that way prior to Python 3.9. Try:

```
from typing import List, Tuple
def myfunc() -> List[Tuple]:
   ...
```

Comment: thanks @Kemp, that works. My import was not including the List and Tuple!

Answer (score 0):

```py
from valdec.decorators import validate
from typing import List, Tuple


@validate("return")
def myfunc(arg) -> List[Tuple[int, ...]]:
    return arg


arg = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
myfunc(arg)  # Ok
```

errors:

```py
arg = (1, 2)
myfunc(arg)  # valdec.errors.ValidationReturnError...
```

```py
arg = "1234"
myfunc(arg)  # valdec.errors.ValidationReturnError...

...
```

`valdec`: https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/valdec